# Should questions have WordPress in the question title?

Tags: discussion, support

I have found that I'm editing a lot of questions recently and when doing so if I find the word WordPress in the question title I more times than not remove it. At the same time I reword the title to be more descriptive of the users problem/question.

This is a WordPress Q&A site after all so saying that your question is about WordPress is pointless as its a given that your question will be about WordPress.

Take this title for example: `Where can I download WordPress themes?` I would reword it to `Where can I download themes for X type of site?`. The only place I wouldn't take out the word WordPress from the title is if its along the lines of: `Integrating WordPress with X`.

So my question is am I OK to remove WordPress from the title if I'm rewording it? Does removing it have any negative effects on the sites SEO or search function if I remove WordPress from the titles? Is it something other editors should consider too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the meta tag from the head:

```
<meta name="title" content="post thumbnails - Displaying a featured image (only img url) as the img src? - WordPress - Stack Exchange">
```

Where the suffix …

> - WordPress - Stack Exchange

… always stays in place.

**So:** No, it shouldn't affect SE results.

**Plus:** I too always try to make titles to sum up the topic + sub case. I think it's better as I'm myself finding it harder and harder to go through tag archives or search results and the titles don't describe what's the Q in general about and if I should take a look at it to maybe find a solution (or hint to one) for my specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

I was actually wondering the same thing when I saw a question like that today. I personally think it should be edited out, *we ALL know this is a WordPress site* (hence the huge word in the header) and we can safely assume that the question is about WordPress.

However if it is a question that is not WP-specific, might as well leave WordPress in the title in case it is migrated to SO or another network (if needed) but I fear when the SO people see 'WordPress' anywhere they want to migrate it here.

Not sure on the impact it has on SEO but I would assume that the search engines will also know that this is a WordPress-specific site. Also I can't imagine somebody searching for "WordPress" here. :)

Just my two cents.

Edit: On another note, I second Rarst's answer. For the sake of not editing a single word in the title for that purpose it shouldn't be *too* important.

Comment: Absolutely; edit it out. *It's a **WordPress** Question and Answer site*.

Answer (score 3):

My personal rule of a thumb - don't mess with titles if there is no pressing cause. I will rewrite the title if it's completely bonkers or question had changed, but I won't touch anything that is clear enough for the sake of minor changes.

Comment: I think you miss-understood me. Im not asking is it ok to go around all questions and remove WordPress from the title. What I'm asking is that during rewording titles to better suit the question at hand is it OK to removed WordPress from it?

Comment: The one's I edit usually take the form of "*WordPress: how to do X?*". In such case, "WordPress" is especially superfluous.

Comment: @Brady that would be very contextual. There can be titles were WordPress is absolutely not needed just as there can be titles where it is essential part of it. You won't edit something like "WordPress vs Drupal" to "vs Drupal", right? :)

Comment: @Rarst - I already answered that in my question: *The only place I wouldn't take out the word WordPress from the title is if its along the lines of: `Integrating WordPress with X.`* This is where WordPress is required in the title